# How can I replicate the Arduino function lowByte in python?

Tags: python, arduino

According to the [Arduino reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LowByte):

> lowByte extracts the low-order (rightmost) byte of a variable

How could I replicate this behavior using Python (2.7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lowByte = lambda b: b & 0xff
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lowByte x:
    return (x % 256)
```

This should do what you (at least seem to) want.

Comment: The arduino function will accept any data type, would your answer work for anything as well?

Comment: I sort of question what you need that for, but if it's for any type, then `bytearray(x)[0]` should work, though I am not certain that there's a single method that works for arbitrary types -- this one may still have some limitations. Is there some specific type that you want to convert, or some specific set of types?

Comment: My program translates the Objective C used by the Arduino into python then runs it, so I need to match the behavior of the native function as closely as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're going to find something that will work better than bytearray, just because python has less of the byte-level structure of variables than any of the C variants do. Bytearray does work on most things, but it does fail on iterables that contain values too large, and it may not work on objects. Essentially, anything that would use pointers in C seems questionable as to how well it will work.

Comment: @qaphla Could you elaborate what you are talking about? What does "bytearray works on most things, but not no iterables" mean?

Comment: `bytearray([256])` will throw an exception, because 256 cannot be converted to a single byte, and similarly for any iterable containing a value outside the range [0,255]. Thus, in general, iterables cannot necessarily be converted to bytearrays.